# Rails - How to utilize different classes in links and images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

So I'm playing with Rails and have a pretty basic question hopefully.

I'm integrating a site that relies on multiple elements nested in a link, but each require specific classes.

```
<a href="index.html" class="example">
    <img src="img/logoWhiteBg.jpg" alt="logo" class="example2" />
    <p class="example3">The <span class="example4">Premier</span> Online <span class="example4">Real Estate</span> Enewsletter</p>
</a>
```

So I'm trying to write it with erb and having trouble nesting all of the classes together in their appropriate places.

How would I nest these together in Rails to produce a product with the above classes?

```
# Link Example
<%= link_to "Home", root_path %>
```

So how do I get it so:

- Link OPEN, adds classes

  - Image inside Link. Adds classes
  - Paragraph inside Link. Adds classes
  - Spans open. Add classes
- Link CLOSE

So its all bundled up in a large clickable area to navigate to an area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `link_to` a block to avoid a bunch of nasty string interpolation in the first argument. Something like:

```
<%= link_to 'index.html', class: :example do %>
   <img src="img/logoWhiteBg.jpg" alt="logo" class="example2" />
   <p class="example3">The <span class="example4">Premier</span> Online <span class="example4">Real Estate</span> Enewsletter</p>
<% end %>
```

(You're also free to use erb in the block).

Check out the docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Thank you tremendously. I was wondering how to make that all work out! I appreciate it. I didn't NEED this immediately but wanted to know how to make it work before I did :-P

Comment: So. Is `<% end %>` required or it just tells it to include everything before then included in the initial `ebr` statement?

Comment: The `<% end %>`  part is a syntax requirement for the erb templating language - you probably want to check out a tutorial there. Glad it worked!

Comment: 2 days into Rails and just getting my bearings. Thank you.